# oracle 10g ddl auditing: ora-00604 error occurred at recursive sql on dbms_metadata

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I want to audit all new tables created in my database by the application team.
The sql_text column of dba_audit_trail is empty, so I created a procedure and trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE bhattd.ddl_logger (
obj_operation varchar2(25),
obj_owner     varchar2(25),
obj_name      varchar2(25),
obj_type      varchar2(25),
obj_text      clob,
obj_when      timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_ddl (o_name varchar2, o_owner varchar2, l_sysevent varchar2) authid current_user IS
count_tab number;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_tab FROM sys.dba_tables WHERE table_name = o_name and owner = o_owner;
IF count_tab = 1 THEN
INSERT INTO bhattd.ddl_logger VALUES (l_sysevent, o_owner, o_name, 'TABLE', sys.dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',o_name,o_owner), systimestamp);
END IF;
END;
```

1st question: If I create a table in my own schema (bhattd) then the procedure works without "authid current_user".  If I execute

```
get_ddl('S_UCM_PRIVACY','SIEBEL','CREATE');
```

then it fails unless I include "authid current_user" in the procedure definition, even though I have the DBA role.  Why is this happening?

Next, I created the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ddl_trigger1 AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
DECLARE
l_sysevent varchar2(25);
BEGIN
SELECT ora_sysevent INTO l_sysevent FROM dual;
IF ( l_sysevent = 'CREATE' )
THEN
BEGIN
bhattd.get_ddl(ora_dict_obj_name,ora_dict_obj_owner,l_sysevent);
END;
END IF;
END;
```

Now, if I try to create a table under schema "SCOTT", I get this error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-31603: object "T1" of type TABLE not found in schema "SCOTT"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2806
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4333
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "BHATTD.GET_DDL", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

2nd question: I think it should have worked without "authid current_user" based on definer's rights.  Then after adding "authid current_user", I think this should work based on invoker's rights (I have the DBA role, which includes execute on dbms_metadata, plus I own the table, procedure, and trigger).  Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: For the first issue, a definer's rights stored procedure doesn't have access to privileges granted through a role (like `DBA`) only those granted via a direct grant.  So you'd need something like `SELECT ANY TABLE` granted directly to you.  For the second issue, the table doesn't fully exist when the trigger is fired.  I expect your trigger would need to submit a job that would run after the DDL completed to extract the DDL.

Comment: For the second issue, I agree with your logic, but I think that this should be the sequence of events:  (1) I issue the create table statement, (2)  there is an implicit commit, (3) the "after create" trigger fires, which should be able to read from dba_tables.

Comment: A DDL statement does two implicit commits (assuming it is successful).  One before it starts and one after it finishes.  The trigger fires before the second implicit commit.  At that point, the changes to the data dictionary are not yet committed.  If your trigger throws an error, for example, the DDL statement should be rolled back.  So within the trigger, you can't query `dba_tables` to see the information about the table that is in the process of being created.